# Scraping html json in python

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want scrape different elements in a website, and I have a problem in a particular part of the html code. This is the html code:

```
  if( window.tc_vars ) {
    tc_vars["owner_sub_category"] = ["CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES"];
  }
  var SellerInformationData = {"customerType":"PRO","reference":"E111477039","account":{"familyCode":"CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES","family":"Centre multimarques","address":{"street1":"3 RUE DAGUERRE","city":"RAMBOUILLET","zipCode":"78120","country":"FRANCE","location":{"longitude":1.8492847,"latitude":48.6527683}},"publishedName":"LES GRANDES OCCASIONS.COM RAMBOUILLET","createdDate":"2022-05-30T17:00:03Z"},"companyCreationDate":"2003-04-01","rating":4.75,"feedbackCount":4,"customShowroomUrl":"les-grandes-occasions-rambouillet.espacevo.fr","classifiedsCount":27}
```

I want the rating and the feedbackcount and I try this code

```
script_tag2 = soup.find('script', text=lambda text: text and 'var SellerInformationData' in text)
        json_str2 = script_tag2.text.strip().replace('var SellerInformationData = ', '').replace(';', '')
        datajsSID = json.loads(json_str2)

        try:
            city = datajsSID['account']['address']['city']
        except:
            city = pd.NA
```

but I have this error, can you help me ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matheoferrer/PycharmProjects/MemoireM2/main.py", line 257, in <module>
    data = json.loads(json_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: `json.loads()` raises this error which means that something is wrong with your parsing.

Comment: I make the same code for an other element in the html code like this and it's worth, why here it's not? `script_tag = soup.find('script', text=lambda text: text and 'var GeneralInformationData' in text)
        json_str = script_tag.text.strip().replace('var GeneralInformationData = ', '').replace(';', '')
        datajsGID = json.loads(json_str)`

Comment: Print `json_str2` before `json.loads()` call and you will see what's wrong with exact string.

Comment: Doesn't  `json_str2` still contain the prior `if` statement at this point?

Comment: @OlvinRoght the print outputs this,`tc_vars["owner_sub_category"] = ["INTERMEDIAIRE"]
  }
  {"customerType":"PRO","reference":"W102598229","account":{"familyCode":"INTERMEDIAIRE","family":"Intermédiaire","address":{"street1":"12 ROUTE DE BAZAS","city":"LANGON",` but if I want to take the city for example and put this it doesn't work `city = datajsSID['account']['address']['city']`normally it's the right tags to access the city but nothing works

Comment: @JonSG no there is no `if`, should I put one somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your `soup.find()` gets the entire tag, not just the line that triggered the filter.

For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<script>
  if( window.tc_vars ) {
    tc_vars["owner_sub_category"] = ["CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES"];
  }
  var SellerInformationData = {"customerType":"PRO","reference":"E111477039","account":{"familyCode":"CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES","family":"Centre multimarques","address":{"street1":"3 RUE DAGUERRE","city":"RAMBOUILLET","zipCode":"78120","country":"FRANCE","location":{"longitude":1.8492847,"latitude":48.6527683}},"publishedName":"LES GRANDES OCCASIONS.COM RAMBOUILLET","createdDate":"2022-05-30T17:00:03Z"},"companyCreationDate":"2003-04-01","rating":4.75,"feedbackCount":4,"customShowroomUrl":"les-grandes-occasions-rambouillet.espacevo.fr","classifiedsCount":27}
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
script_tag2 = soup.find('script', text=lambda text: text and 'var SellerInformationData' in text)

print(script_tag2)
```

Will give you:

```
  if( window.tc_vars ) {
    tc_vars["owner_sub_category"] = ["CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES"];
  }
  var SellerInformationData = {"customerType":"PRO","reference":"E111477039","account":{"familyCode":"CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES","family":"Centre multimarques","address":{"street1":"3 RUE DAGUERRE","city":"RAMBOUILLET","zipCode":"78120","country":"FRANCE","location":{"longitude":1.8492847,"latitude":48.6527683}},"publishedName":"LES GRANDES OCCASIONS.COM RAMBOUILLET","createdDate":"2022-05-30T17:00:03Z"},"companyCreationDate":"2003-04-01","rating":4.75,"feedbackCount":4,"customShowroomUrl":"les-grandes-occasions-rambouillet.espacevo.fr","classifiedsCount":27}
```

When you `replace('var SellerInformationData = ', '')` you are still left with the `if` statement.

```
if( window.tc_vars ) {
    tc_vars["owner_sub_category"] = ["CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES"]
  }
  {"customerType":"PRO","reference":"E111477039","account":{"familyCode":"CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES","family":"Centre multimarques","address":{"street1":"3 RUE DAGUERRE","city":"RAMBOUILLET","zipCode":"78120","country":"FRANCE","location":{"longitude":1.8492847,"latitude":48.6527683}},"publishedName":"LES GRANDES OCCASIONS.COM RAMBOUILLET","createdDate":"2022-05-30T17:00:03Z"},"companyCreationDate":"2003-04-01","rating":4.75,"feedbackCount":4,"customShowroomUrl":"les-grandes-occasions-rambouillet.espacevo.fr","classifiedsCount":27}
```

Which of course is not valid json.

You need to pick out that line either by something like the `re` package or by hand by inspecting the line of that script block. Try:

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<script>
  if( window.tc_vars ) {
    tc_vars["owner_sub_category"] = ["CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES"];
  }
  var SellerInformationData = {"customerType":"PRO","reference":"E111477039","account":{"familyCode":"CENTRE_MULTIMARQUES","family":"Centre multimarques","address":{"street1":"3 RUE DAGUERRE","city":"RAMBOUILLET","zipCode":"78120","country":"FRANCE","location":{"longitude":1.8492847,"latitude":48.6527683}},"publishedName":"LES GRANDES OCCASIONS.COM RAMBOUILLET","createdDate":"2022-05-30T17:00:03Z"},"companyCreationDate":"2003-04-01","rating":4.75,"feedbackCount":4,"customShowroomUrl":"les-grandes-occasions-rambouillet.espacevo.fr","classifiedsCount":27}
</script>
"""

prefix = "var SellerInformationData = "
suffix = ";"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
script_tag2 = soup.find('script', text=lambda text: text and prefix in text)

datajsSID = {}
for line in script_tag2.text.split("\n"):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(prefix):
        line = line.removeprefix(prefix).removesuffix(suffix)
        datajsSID = json.loads(line)
        break

city = datajsSID.get("account",{}).get("address",{}).get("city")
print(f"City: {city}")

rating = datajsSID.get("rating")
print(f"Rating: {rating}")
```

That should give you:

```
City: RAMBOUILLET
Rating: 4.75
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly. Just a small question in addition, to have "rating" for example, the code does not work. Is there anything specific that needs to be changed?

Comment: rating is just at a different path `rating = datajsSID.get("rating")
`

Comment: Yes but the result is "None" when I do that

Comment: not when I do it... I'll update my answer now

Comment: It's strange I do the exact same thing and I have nothing. But it doesn't matter I'll try to find, thanks again

Comment: this data is present elsewhere in the page and is like this:
```
if( window.tc_vars ) {
    tc_vars["rating_satisfaction"] = 4.75;
    tc_vars["rating_count"] = 4;
}
```
and i tried that without success    
```
        script_tag_regex = r'<script>window\.tc_vars = window\.tc_vars \|\| \[\](.*?)</script>'
        script_tag = re.findall(script_tag_regex, response.text, re.DOTALL)[0]
 rating_regex = r'tc_vars\["rating_satisfaction"\] = (.*?);'
 rating = re.findall(rating_regex, script_tag)[0]
```
What do you think ?

Comment: same strategy should work with `prefix = "tc_vars[\"rating_satisfaction\"] = "`